# Windows 10 comes as restart after selecting hibernate

Tags: windows-10

I usually click hibernate when I finish my work and the next day when I start my computer, everything is there like the day before, but these day when I start my computer after putting it to hibernate the day before, it comes like if I restarted. It's some kind of configuration or my machine has something wrong?

Comment: It may be shutting down when you press hibernate.  I suggest updating BIOS, Chipset (if there is a Chipset driver), and Power Driver. Do these, restart, make sure Hibernate settings are correct, and then try hibernating again.

Comment: ok thank you John!

Comment: Please let us know if this is a solution for you.